# Yii2. Как добавить в WHERE IN кастомный QUERY запрос

Tags: sql, yii2

У меня есть такой запрос WHERE.

```
where
  (posts.id in (
    select posts.id from posts
    where posts.carId in (
      select car_subscription.carId from car_subscription
      where car_subscription.userId = 37
    )
  )
  or
    posts.id in (
    select posts.id from posts
    where posts.userId in (
      select user_subscription.userSubId from user_subscription
      where user_subscription.userId = 37
    )
  ) )
```

Как построить такой запрос с помощью yii2?. Как в where in вставить SELECT

```
    $query->where(['in', 'posts.id', ''])
            ->orWhere(['in', 'posts.id', '']);
```

Comment: Мой совет: забить и не мучиться с этими построителями  и работать например с DAO. Потому что в итоге это построенно  месиво трудно читать вообще кому либо.....ну и составлять эти запросы тоже, как мы видим

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я так понял это createCommand? Но createCommand ломает мне типизацию данных. Как быть с этой проблемой?

Comment: Если бы я ещё понял что вы имеет в виду под " ломает мне типизацию данных" .... где ломает, как ломает, что значит "ломает" и т.д.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Когда я делаю $query->all(). мне возвращает обьект с типами. id=> integer , number -> integer, title -> string и так далее. Если я делаю createComman->queryAll() -> все данные будут стрингой.

Comment: Зависит от того как дальше этим пользоваться.... нужно ли оно вообще........ а так, простой $model->load вполне справится с этим

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Тоесть получить данные , а затем сделать $model->load который сделает мне типизацию? а как быть с afterFind и так далее?

Comment: А что мешает изначально из БД получать данные в том формате, который необходим? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  

Comment: @АлексейШиманский используя createCommand->queryAll() yii2 не вернет мне данные в формате который необходим... + afterFind не сработает

Comment: Ты не понял. Ты в afterFind делаешь точно такие же операции, которые можно было бы вытянуть сразу с помощью БД. Тем более операция в БД была бы быстрее и не пришлось бы нагружать сервер лишний раз конвертациями

Comment: @АлексейШиманский afterFind у меня делает запрос в redis.

Comment: А это уже ошибка проектирования. С чего бы модели вдруг тянуться в редис? Это нарушение ответственности

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне нужно получить лайк сразу после того как найду данную

Comment: @АлексейШиманский также я добавил свойство в моей модели posts `public $liked`

Answer (score 0):

В Yii2 можете использовать Query Builder для создания SQL-запроса с подобной структурой. Вот пример построения конструктора в Yii2:

```
$subquery1 = (new Query())
->select(['posts.id'])
->from('posts')
->where(['in', 'posts.carId', (new Query())
    ->select(['car_subscription.carId'])
    ->from('car_subscription')
    ->where(['car_subscription.userId' => 37])
]);

$subquery2 = (new Query())
    ->select(['posts.id'])
    ->from('posts')
    ->where(['in', 'posts.userId', (new Query())
        ->select(['user_subscription.userSubId'])
        ->from('user_subscription')
        ->where(['user_subscription.userId' => 37])
    ]);

$query = (new Query())
    ->select(['*'])
    ->from('posts')
    ->where(['or', ['in', 'posts.id', $subquery1], ['in', 'posts.id', $subquery2]]);

$results = $query->all();
```